# Postgresql why is INNER JOIN so much slower than WHERE

Tags: sql, postgresql, inner-join

I have 2 tables where I copy file name from one table to another in an update operation. Using INNER JOIN makes the query run in 22 seconds when there are just ~4000 rows. Using a WHERE clause allows it to run it in about 200 milliseconds. How and why is this happening, does the INNER JOIN result in additional looping?

Example 1 using INNER JOIN - Takes 22 seconds when table a has about 4k records.

```
UPDATE table_a SET file_name = tmp.file_name FROM
(
    SELECT b.customer_id, b.file_name, b.file_id FROM table_b AS b WHERE b.status = 'A'
) tmp
INNER JOIN table_a AS a
    ON tmp.customer_id=a.customer_id AND tmp.file_id=a.file_id;
```

Example 2 using WHERE runs in about 200 ms.

```
UPDATE table_a AS a SET file_name = tmp.file_name FROM
(
    SELECT b.customer_id, b.file_name, b.file_id FROM table_b AS b WHERE b.status = 'A'
) tmp
WHERE tmp.customer_id=a.customer_id AND tmp.file_id=a.file_id;
```

Comment: I think the first query is missing information that connects the first reference to `table_a` to the second one. Because of that, I think it updates waaay more data, (all rows, multiple times). So, what is your goal anyway with the first query? Why would you want to write it like that?

Comment: Yes, that seems to be it. I was just wondering how the INNER JOIN ended up being a cross join and it looks like it is because the 2 table a references are different.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The queries are doing totally different things.  The first is updating *every row* in `table_a` with the expression.  I am guessing that there are even multiple updates on the same row.

The two `table_a`s in the first version are *two different references to the table*.  The effect is a `cross join` because you have no conditions combining them.

The second method is the correct syntax for what you want to do in Postgres.

Comment: Out of curiosity, how can the equivalent of the second query be written in terms of INNER JOIN?

Comment: @Abe . . . You need `join` conditions (in the `where` clause between `table_a` and `a`) -- perhaps on the primary key.